# PHP: regex, preg_split

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that has a content like this.

```
19. Which of the following conflicting criteria does the problem below satisfe. 2.1
C++ pointers are powerful and very flexible but at the cost of poor intelligibility.
a.  Writability vs Readability
b.  Reliability vs Cost of execution
c.  Writability vs Reliability
d.  Cost of execution vs. Readability
e.  Cost of execution vs. Readability
```

What I want to do is to split it like this.

```
    [0] => 19.  Which of the following conflicting criteria does the problem below satisfye. 2.1
C++ pointers are powerful and very flexible but at the cost of poor intelligibility.

    [1] => a.   Writability vs Readability

    [2] => b.   Reliability vs Cost of execution

    [3] => c.   Writability vs Reliability

    [4] => d.   Cost of execution vs. Readability

    [5] => e.   Cost of execution vs. Readability
```

My regex is weak and I am having this kind of result.

```
preg_split('/(?=[a-e\d]+\.(?!\d))/', $entries, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    [0] => 1
    [1] => 9.   Which of the following conflicting criteria does the problem below satisfy
    [2] => e. 2.1
C++ pointers are powerful and very flexible but at the cost of poor intelligibility.

    [3] => a.   Writability vs Readability

    [4] => b.   Reliability vs Cost of execution

    [5] => c.   Writability vs Reliability

    [6] => d.   Cost of execution vs. Readability

    [7] => e.   Cost of execution vs. Readability
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Why not explode on newlines? Is `C++ pointers are powerful` on its own line? How does `e.` get generated?

Comment: C++ pointers are powerful is part of the 1st line. I can't explode it.

Comment: Why can't you explode it then? Explode works fine on local test... I still don't see where `e` comes from but I think that is a typo?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't get the question. I can explode it but I have to place "C++ pointers are powerful" on the line of "Which of the following... satisfye 2.1"

Comment: Oh okay, so `C++ pointers are powerful and very fl` should not be its own line but it currently is. How is the `e` point generated? Just duplicate the last value?

Comment: "e." is generated because of the [a-e\d]. My regex is weak that's why "satisfye 2.1" is split

Comment: In your provided sample string there is no `e`. `e.   Cost of execution vs. Readability`

Comment: Ohh that, I'm sorry. My sample string is incorrect. Gonna update it.

Comment: If `2.1 C++ pointers are powerful and very flexible but at the cost of poor intelligibility.` is own its own line you're going to need a different regex than the answer provided. If it is not than explode is much easier.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it. Thank you for giving me new ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to split at one or more [\v](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) vertical spaces, if there's `^[a-e\d]+\.` [ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (starting the following line). [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function is fine:

```
$pattern = '/\v+(?=^[a-e\d]+\.)/m';
```

`m` is the multiline flag for making the `^` caret match line start (not only string start).

```
print_r(preg_split($pattern, $str));
```

[test at eval.in](https://eval.in/393091); should give the desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 19. Which of the following conflicting criteria does the problem below satisfe. 2.1
C++ pointers are powerful and very flexible but at the cost of poor intelligibility.
    [1] => a.  Writability vs Readability
    [2] => b.  Reliability vs Cost of execution
    [3] => c.  Writability vs Reliability
    [4] => d.  Cost of execution vs. Readability
    [5] => e.  Cost of execution vs. Readability
)
```

Also [see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mM3hC3/1) for testing the split sequence. If there's empty lines with spaces in between, try `\s+` (one or more of any whitespace) instead of `\v+`.

Comment: I apologize for my late response, this really helped me!

Comment: @Ian Great this helps you! ツ was also a late answer

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to break each line up...

```
$str = "19. Which of the following conflicting criteria does the problem below satisfe. 2.1 C++ pointers are powerful and very flexible but at the cost of poor intelligibility.
a.  Writability vs Readability
b.  Reliability vs Cost of execution
c.  Writability vs Reliability
d.  Cost of execution vs. Readability
";

preg_match_all('/(.*)\n/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Will give you

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
        [0]=>
        string(169) "19. Which of the following conflicting criteria does the problem below satisfe. 2.1    C++ pointers are powerful and very flexible but at the cost of poor intelligibility.
        "
        [1]=>
        string(32) "a.  Writability vs Readability
        "
        [2]=>
        string(38) "b.  Reliability vs Cost of execution
        "
        [3]=>
        string(32) "c.  Writability vs Reliability
        "
        [4]=>
        string(39) "d.  Cost of execution vs. Readability
        "
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
        [0]=>
        string(168) "19. Which of the following conflicting criteria does the problem below satisfe. 2.1    C++ pointers are powerful and very flexible but at the cost of poor intelligibility."
        [1]=>
        string(31) "a.  Writability vs Readability"
        [2]=>
        string(37) "b.  Reliability vs Cost of execution"
        [3]=>
        string(31) "c.  Writability vs Reliability"
        [4]=>
        string(38) "d.  Cost of execution vs. Readability"
    }
}
```

`preg_match_all()` will give you the ability to match the pattern over multiple lines and the `$matches` array will give you all the matches. Since it will treat the whole line (including \n) as a match, that's the first array. So you want the part matched by `(.*)` which is in the second element of the `$matches` array.

Comment: Props for this detailed explanation! Thank you, I'll look on this approach.